# unique SessionID inside a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, session, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008) that uses only temp tables.  So I can easily have 2 instances of this sp running in parallel without interfering with each other.

Does each instance have a unique Session-ID or an identifier?  For example, if I put a command such as `SELECT SESSION_ID` inside the sp, it will print a different number/characters for each of the 2 sp calls.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to check it? And what is session_id at all?

Comment: Are you concerned about multiple calls to this stored procedure will create multiple Temp tables with same name ?

Comment: @M.Ali No. I know that multiple calls won't interfere.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I think what I was looking for was SELECT @@SPID .  It looks like that a different call to the server should end up having a new SPID.  So that should work.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Temp tables help me run the same sp in parallel.  However, they slow down the sp as they become big.  Im creating tables now on the fly (dynamic programming) using SPID+CurrentTimeStamp+ RandomString to store the same data.  This way, multiple calls to the same sp won't interfere with each other and still run fast.

Comment: Create your temp table by prefixing the name with # sign, e.g. `CREATE TABLE #temptable (...)` - that way you don't need to care about session ID or anything, SQL Server will create as many copies of temp table as needed, and they will not interfere with each other, and you still access them by just `#temptable` name. Please search for "Temporary tables" in this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx